# SQL - Case statement with multiple then

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using T-SQL and I am trying to have a then statement return multiple values so I can search the 'Year' column for multiple years.

If the year is greater than 2013, then I want to search the current year and the previous year.  So if the year is 2016, I want to search for 2016 AND 2015.

This code does not work, but this is what I am trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB_NAME].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] 
WHERE 
YR_CLMN in 
(
case when YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2013 then YEAR(GETDATE()) 
when YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2013 then (YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())-1)
end
)
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Ew don't use in's where possible! Although this is one select statement and seems neater, it would probably be better to break this down into bitesize chunks :)

Comment: Do you really expect Year(GetDate()) to return 2013 or less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question , but I believe it will give you what you want

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB_NAME].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] 
WHERE 
YR_CLMN >= 
(
case when YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2013 then YEAR(GETDATE())-1) 
ELSE YEAR(GETDATE())
end
) AND YR_CLMN <= YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Here's the

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81451/1)

Comment: @SHAKIR SHABBIR: Checked; I believe it works as expected (at least how I understood requirements - if current year is greater than 2013, i.e. 2014,2015,.... , then return records from the table where year between previous and current; if current year is 2013 and less, than return data for the current year only). I might have misunderstood what is needed though...

Comment: I also believe the requirement is what you have got.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM [DB_NAME].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] 
WHERE YR_CLMN in 
(YEAR(GETDATE()), 
 case when YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2013 then YEAR(GETDATE())-1 else YEAR(GETDATE()) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Dates Table
(
  YR_CLMN DateTime
  BringOut bit DEFAULT ( 0 )
)

--Get all columns
INSERT INTO @Dates ( YR_CLMN )
SELECT YR_CLMN
FROM [dbo].[YourTable]

--Where YR_CLMN = 2013
UPDATE @Dates SET BringOut = 1
WHERE YEAR(YR_CLMN) = 2013

--Where YR_CLMN is within a year of now
UPDATE @Dates SET BringOut = 1
WHERE YEAR(YR_CLMN) = YEAR(GETDATE()) OR YEAR(YR_CLMN) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1

SELECT YR_CLMN
FROM @Dates
WHERE BringOut = 1
```

Alternatively, if the above approach isn't acceptable. You are essentially saying if `YR_CLMN = 2013 OR (YR_CLMN = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND YR_CLMN = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)`, using `IN` really isn't very productive in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good suggestions so far, so I'm going to take a slightly different course.

Let's assume that you've got access to a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable).  If not, go get one!  : )  Let's also assume it's named `Numbers` with column `Number`.

Also, let's use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for readability.  This makes a really neat query.

```
; WITH ValidYears AS
(
    SELECT Number AS ValidYear
    FROM [dbo].[Numbers]
    WHERE Number >=  2013
        AND Number >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
        AND NUmber <= YEAR(GETDATE())
)
SELECT *
FROM [DBName].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] a
JOIN ValidYears b
    ON a.YR_CLMN = b.ValidYear
```

What I like about this is that you separate the query into logical units.  The CTE handles the year logic, and the following query decides what to do with it.

You don't have to use a numbers table, of course; I just think it looks nicer.

Here's an example of my local numbers table, and what the CTE results would look like.  If you've indexed correctly, there will be a clustered index seek - very efficient.  (side note: my table is named "Integers")

```
DECLARE @CurrentYear INT
SET @CurrentYear = 2016

SELECT value AS ValidYear
FROM [dbo].Integers
WHERE value >=  2013
    AND value >= @CurrentYear - 1
    AND value <= @CurrentYear
```